# Defining analogue (similar) colors

Tags: python, colors, transform

I want to do a program that take the color from a image, and than give me the analogue colors...,
but I don't know how I can use the color taken from the image because it doesn't give me the colors like the object...

I tried to make like this:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("C:/Marco/programas/orange2.jpg").convert("P")

colors = []

for cor_rgb in img.getpalette():
    if cor_rgb not in colors:
        colors.append(cor_rgb)
c = Image.Image.getdata(img)

print(c)
print (colors)
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: documentation for [getpalette](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getpalette) shows that it gives it as flat list - `[R,G,B, ... ]`.Using `numpy.array` you could reshape it to array `[ [R,G,B], [...], ...]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use specify an adaptive conversion when you use the [`Image.convert()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert) method. The details aren't given but "adaptive" in this context usually means the set colors that best represents those in the image.

After doing the conversion, the value returned by `Image.getpalette()` is a list of RGB colors representing each of the colors the adaptive algorithm chose to put into the palette. From the looks of the results using my test image, it looks like the colors are in the table ordered by popularity (but I'm not sure and it's not documented).

Professional image editing programs like Adobe Photoshop®, have several options when converting to a paletted image, including "selective", "uniform", and "perceptual". I often use the latter because it takes into consideration the fact that the human eye can't detect differences between all color equally, it using some metric to measure "perceptual color difference".

```
from PIL import Image

image_filename = "oranges2.jpg"
img = Image.open(image_filename).convert("P", palette=Image.ADAPTIVE)
palette = img.getpalette()
colors = [palette[i:i+3]  # Split palette entries up into groups of 3.
            for i in range(0, len(palette), 3)]

print(len(colors))
for color in colors:
    print(color)
```

Sample output:

```
256
[250, 212, 69]
[253, 194, 17]
[252, 185, 22]
[254, 185, 1]
[255, 177, 10]
[255, 177, 2]
[255, 177, 0]
[254, 177, 2]
[240, 177, 35]
[255, 167, 10]
[255, 168, 4]
[255, 167, 2]
...
[115, 15, 1]
[98, 19, 1]
[98, 11, 1]
[86, 16, 2]
[75, 15, 2]
[83, 7, 1]
[72, 7, 1]
[58, 12, 3]
[56, 6, 1]
[59, 3, 1]
[48, 3, 1]
[36, 8, 3]
[36, 2, 1]
[20, 6, 3]
[18, 2, 1]
```

Here's the image file I used for testing:

[image]

Comment: After downsampling you have the indexed color image and the correct palette – only 256 entries. If you really want to know the actual frequency, loop over the image again and count. `:)` (Which, actually, PIL of course already did, but it's no use if this data isn't exposed to the user...)

Comment: @usr2564301: It would probably be much faster to use the [`Image.histogram()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.histogram) function. Nothing requires the colors in the palette to exactly match any of them in the original image they only have to be "close". The algorithm used may simply be trying to minimize the differences between the pixels in original and paletted versions of the image — but again the documentation says nothing about the technique is being used.Might be possible to use `histogram()` to determine the "analogue" colors the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for [getpalette](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getpalette) shows that it gives it as flat list `[R,G,B, ... ]`. Using `numpy.array` you could reshape it to array `[ [R,G,B], [...], ...]` and get unique elements

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy

img = Image.open("image.jpg").convert("P")

colors = numpy.array(img.getpalette())
colors = colors.reshape((-1,3))
colors = numpy.unique(colors, axis=0)

print(colors)
```

Example result

```
[[  0   0   0]
 [  0   0  51]
 [  0   0 102]
 [  0   0 153]
 [  0   0 204]
 [  0   0 255]
 [  0  51   0]
 [  0  51  51]
 [  0  51 102]
 [  0  51 153]
 [  0  51 204]
 [  0  51 255]
 [  0 102   0]
 [  0 102  51]
 [  0 102 102]
 [  0 102 153]
 [  0 102 204]
 [  0 102 255]
```

But I don't know how to define "analogue colors"

Comment: Thanks guys, but can a use this results for any other operation ? For example: take the color orange and use the numbers (255, 177, 35) to put it in an line to do something? Or I can't use this results ?